# All threads in tracee process stop when tracer exits before detach using ptrace

Tags: behavior, terminate, ptrace

I am having trouble creating the behaviour described in the *attaching and detaching* section in [ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html):

```
If the tracer dies, all tracees are automatically detached and
restarted, unless they were in group-stop.
```

I have a process (the tracee) that consists of multiple threads which I attach to using `ptrace`. Using a separate process(the tracer) using the following calls:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0);
sleep(3600);
```

When the tracer dies(using ctrl+c or kill -9) while sleeping and still attached to a process, I notice that all the threads of the tracee process are being put in a stopped state instead of continuing execution.

I have also tried using GDB to reproduce this problem since GDB also attaches to a process using ptrace. But when killing gdb(using kill -9) while attached the the tracee, all the threads of the tracee do continue executing as expected.
I have tried looked at source of GDB but have yet been unable to figure anything out.

Does anyone know what could cause the behaviour of all the tracee's threads being stopped when the tracer dies?

This is being evaluated on an ARM Cortex-A9 CPU using kernel 3.6.5

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, sending a SIGCONT to the process will allow the process to continue after detach. Signals are held until you PTRACE_DETACH. Can you try this?